# Managing Multiple Variable Values within a String in Flowgorithm

Tags: flowgorithm

I'm attempting to display a string containing multiple placeholder values, so far, I've attempted this approach:

`"3* Product: {prod3NoVAT}€ + VAT (22%%), Total: {prod3VAT}€"`

However, it's not producing the expected output. The only solution I've found to work is:

`"[...] Product: " &prod3NoVAT`

But I believe this would require me to create numerous lines of "code" for each product, which seems impractical. I'm relatively new to Flowgorithm, and I haven't been able to find much information online. Can anyone provide guidance or assistance?

Answer (score 0):

You can concatenate strings and numbers with `&` in a single expression:

`"3* Product: " & prod3NoVAT & "€ + VAT (22%%), Total: " & prod3VAT & "€"`